# Why Byte array doesn't show all parameters ? (Print Byte Array)

Tags: python

I want to know why the byte array doesn't show us all the parameters.
Here is the code that I used, and the result shows that they missed the last byte (`\x20`).
Can anyone explain it?

```py
size = 4
data = "00C01020"
data_array = bytearray(size)
for i in range(size):
    data_split = data[2 * i:2 * (i + 1)]
    data_array[i] = int(data_split, 16)

print(data_array[0])
print(data_array[1])
print(data_array[2])
print(data_array[3])
print(data_array)
```

```
0
192
16
32
bytearray(b'\x00\xc0\x10 ')
```

Comment: It is printed as the ASCI character with number 32, which is a space (" ").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\x20` is a space character. Printable ASCII characters are printed as is, not as byte escapes. The space is there, quite visibly:

```
bytearray(b'\x00\xc0\x10 ')
```

Comment: I got it! It's amazing though